# JSON parsing from cross domain using jquery ajax

Tags: json, jquery

Im trying to parse json from cross domain but im getting error like **405 (Method Not Allowed)  in jquery plugin (im using latest plugin only from google)** Any solution or suggestions will be great help for me.

Thanks
Basha

**Here is my code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myurl.com/webservice&callback=?",          
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: "{}",
    Accept: "",
    beforeSend: setHeader,
    success: OnGetAllMembersSuccess,
    error: OnGetAllMembersError,                
    });
});     
function setHeader(req) {
    req.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic credentials");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
}    

function OnGetAllMembersSuccess(data, status) {
    alert(status);
    $.each(data.result, function(key, value) {              
        $("#result").append(key+" : "+value);
        $("#result").append("<br />");
    });
}

function OnGetAllMembersError(request, status, error) {
    alert(status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using jsonp as dataType, you need to bind a call back function in the server side..
for example, if you need a json response like {"id":"myId"}, at the server side it should be return like "mycallback({"id":"myId"})";

Also you need to write that function in client side too.

```
function mycallback(json)
{alert(json);}
```